# Indicator applet in MATE

Tags: 12.04, indicator, gnome-panel, panel, mate

I hate gnome3, so I installed MATE (gnome2 fork) in my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. It's pretty good, but I have a problem: it doesn’t have (or I haven't found)  a working indicator applet on the top panel. I installed `mate-indicator-applet` package, but it displays only a message icon, but I need  volume-control with rythmbox panel, ubuntu1 and a system menu (logoff, shutdown, hibernate, etc.)

So is it possible to set the indicator  applet like the normal gnome?

This is what I have:  [image: This is what I have]

And this what I want to have:   [image: And this what I want to have]

Comment: Anyone? Please!

Answer (score 5):

To get the other indicators, run:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound-gtk2 indicator-application-gtk2 indicator-datetime-gtk2 indicator-session-gtk2 indicator-messages-gtk2
```

Once these are installed, remove the indicator applet from your MATE panel and add the "Indicator applet complete" applet to the panel to reload the indicators. The ubuntu one icon is in the message icon's menu.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that only indicator-sound-gtk2 and indicator-application-gtk2 exist in 12.10; the others are not available under MATE or XFCE desktops.

Comment: +1: `indicator-sound-gtk2` was exactly what I was looking for on my Ubuntu MATE 14.10 :-)